# 條 or 個 as classifier for road (路) in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese, topolect, measure-word

I usually hear 路 used with 條 as the classifier, but sometimes people also use 個. in cantonese, which is the correct classifier? are both correct?

Comment: Note that a lot of people may use 个/個 as the classifier due to [量词个化](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_classifier#Neutralization). In casual parlance I don't think it's too big of a deal.

Comment: sorry, what is 量词个化? and @fyears suggests 個 is not really used? so you have heard people use 個?

Comment: @congusbongus The reference articles for 量词个化 in the Wikipedia entry seem to be discussing Mandarin rather than Cantonese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"條" is the correct one. I speak Cantonese and never heard of "個" in this case.

Comment: that's what i thought, too. if you watch the first few min of this TVB clip (http://www.gooddrama.net/hong-kong-drama/sniper-standoff-episode-17), specifically at the 2:50 mark. it seems like they are referring to 個路. or not?

Comment: @Crashalot No, what the character says is "箇條路", not "個路". The "箇" (more commonly written as 嗰) here means "that", and the phrase "箇條路" in the script means "that path".

Comment: @user1551 While 嗰 can be pronounced as go2 or go3, in that clip it's pronounced as go2, which cannot be substituted by 箇.

Comment: @TactMayers 箇 can be pronounced as go3. In fact, it was the dominant character for "that" (go3) in Qing dynasty's Cantonese songs (粵謳). In contrast, 嗰 was less frequently used in lyrics. But for some curious reasons, the pronunciation go3 is not listed for 箇 in many contemporary dictionaries.

Comment: cool, thanks guys! sometimes they speak too fast, and it's difficult to understand what they're saying. :)

Comment: Ahhh, typos: in my last comment, all occurrences of go3 should read go2. "That" is go2, not go3. I think I need some coffee.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, people who are bilingual in Mandarin and Cantonese might use 個 and 條 as classifier interchangeably for road (路). In Chinese, 個 is a universal classifier or measure word for objects, you might hear it in many occasions to count a "stuff" even for a native speaker.

Comment: so this is different from what @fyers said? (this is for cantonese as well.)

Comment: I think in this case it is very rare. For such a common noun, road (路), it sounds very odd to use the universal classifier while it's taught early in school that 條 is the specific one. Saying 一個路 to native speakers and they'll certainly feel puzzled/hilarious.

Answer (score 0):

條(tiu4) is the proper classifier for 路(lou6).  You have been hearing 個(go3) might because the person was referring to 路(lou6) 口(hau2), which means the corner of the street.